# getopt(3) On mac os and CentOS

Tags: c, macos, centos, getopt

I compile the same code by gcc on OSX and CentOS:

```
while (( opt = getopt (argc, argv, "hp:" )) != -1 )
    {
        fprintf (stderr,"+++++++++++ %d\n\n", opt );
        switch ( opt )
            {
            case 'h':
                    fprintf(stderr, "Help Page \n %s", help_str);
                    return 1;

            case 'p':
                    filename = optarg ;
                    fprintf(stderr,"================== %s\n",optarg);
                    break;

            case '?':
                    printf("ZHZHZHZHZHUT\n");
                    return 3;

            default:
                break;
            }
    }
```

Then I try to run `./a.out -p ./file.txt ya.ru` and `./a.out ya.ru -p ./file.txt`
On CentOS 6.5 both variants work.

But on MAC OS X(10.9) variant `./a.out ya.ru -p ./file.txt` (free parameter before dependent parameter ) does not work. 
`-p` and `/file.txt` are used as simple arguments (not by `getopt`).

Full code is [here](http://yadi.sk/d/JcbTMrziQ5xMr)

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [documented](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getopt) behaviour of GNU `getopt()` is to stop at the first non-option argument only when in POSIX mode, which can be set via a `+` at the start of the option string or by setting the `POSIXLY_CORRECT` environment variable.

In its default mode, GNU `getopt()` 'permutes the contents of `argv` as it scans, so eventually all the non-options are at the end.'

You are hitting this difference in the behaviour — it is the difference between GNU `getopt()` and BSD `getopt()` behaviour, because the BSD `getopt()` has POSIX semantics.

Comment: It's GNU getopt vs BSD/posix getopt behavior. You're describing GNU getopt, which as an extension handles option arguments anywhere by default. BSD getopt stops at the first non option character. (Which GNU getopt will do too if you set the POSIXLY_CORRECT env variable)

Comment: @nos Indeed. The intent of my parenthetical comment was to indicate that the `POSIX` behaviour distinction is also the distinction between GNU and BSD getopt... but I see that that wasn't clear enough. I've edited the comment to hopefully be more clear.

Comment: `brew install gnu-getopt` if you'd like